# How to call one stored procedure from another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

How to call one stored procedure from another stored procedure and when I do that. Then it is not updating in Crystal Report field explorer.

This is my code:

**SP1**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSpecialJournalInfoByJVID]
    (@JvID numeric,@BusinessID numeric)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM JV 
    WHERE jvID = @JvID AND BusinessID = @BusinessID
END
```

**SP2**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger]
    @JvID                           numeric(18,0),
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ParamDate1                     datetime,
    @ParamDate2                     datetime,
    @ParamBusinessID                numeric(18,0),  
    @ParamAccountID                 numeric(18,0),
    @ParamCurrentCurrencyRate       decimal(18,10) =1
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM JV 
    WHERE jvID = @JvID

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        COA.ACCOUNTID, COA.ACCOUNTNAME, COA.GLCODE,
        COA.DESCRIPTION AS ACCOUNTDESCRIPTION,
        COA.ISBANKACCOUNT, COA.BANKACCOUNTNO,
        COA.REFACCOUNT, FIXED,
        ISNULL(OPBAL.OPENINGBALANCE, 0) OPENINGBALANCE,
        ISNULL(CURBAL.DR_CUR_BAL, 0) DR_CUR_BAL,
        ISNULL(CURBAL.CR_CUR_BAL, 0) CR_CUR_BAL,
        J.TRNDATE, J.TRNDESCRIPTION, TRNTYPE,
```

I need help, I googled it a lot but didn't got any solution

thanks in advance...

Comment: who is supposed to call whom?

Comment: SP2 is supposed to call SP1 and i want the only parameter in SP2 from SP1 is @JVID

Comment: Can you identify for what purpose/at what place of SP2 should SP1 be executed? Are you attempting to use SP1 resultset as a source for some query in SP2?

Comment: I want to use SP1 result in Sp2 .all i want is to access the JVID of SP1 in the SP2

Comment: Is that a full source of SP1?

Comment: **This is the full source of SP1**
USE [WebPOS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSpecialJournalInfoByJVID]    Script Date: 2/27/2016 1:09:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSpecialJournalInfoByJVID]
 (@JvID numeric,@BusinessID numeric)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * from JV where jvID=@JvID AND BusinessID=@BusinessID
END

Comment: This is a trivial `select`. You can write it in SP2. Stored procedure is not supposed to be a `datasource` of another query. _Table-valued function_ or _inline function_ may be such a source for query, but I recommend you not to try to convert everything in functions - just try to write that query where you need it. There is no _complicated business logic_, there is an ordinary table filtering by two IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a stored procedure by using the `EXEC` command. However, it might be better to use SQL Server user-defined function.

Please see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085(v=sql.80).aspx