# Can I replace a very complex SQL Select with parameters with a view?

Tags: sql-server

I have a multi table SQL Select that is over 150 lines long, with two input parameters that are used inside one of the inner areas of the select. They are not simply used for where's to limit data retrieved at the end. The parameters are used on the inner areas of the select.

Right now the SQL Select is part of a stored procedure with two input params.  It's ALWAYS called from other stored procedures at the end of them.

Would it be a good idea to replace this with a view and if so can I somehow provide the input parameters to the view?

Comment: I will go with function with two input parameter. View will pull the entire data and you have to filter the records. Through function you can pull only the required records

Comment: A View can't have input paramters. Function is one option. What do you want to achieve ? Are you having performance issue with the query ?

Comment: why not just stay with the stored procedure? do you now need access to the same query some other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667662/how-to-call-one-stored-procedure-from-another-in-sql-server?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't create view with parameters. Instead, you can create a function which takes input parameters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.func (@Parameter varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
 SELECT Field1, Field2,....
 FROM table1
 WHERE Field3 = @Parameter
);
```

Basically view acts just like a table, and the only way that you can add "`parameters`" to a table is via filter statements when accessing the view.